# Fill xaml rectangle multiples solidcolorbrush

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

This type of fill in rectangle in xaml  is it possible?

[image]

I don't want to use gradient to fill the rectangle,  as  in the image per section using solid colorbrush different.

Thanks

Comment: You can put 3 rectangles of specified colors side by side.

Comment: I thought this before but, some of my rectangles has 1,2,3 or 4 sections, and the colors will bind in viedmodel, create N rectangles i think is to dificult for achieve this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Rectangle Width="300" Height="100" Stroke="black" StrokeThickness="3">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 0">
      <GradientStop Color="red" Offset="0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="red" Offset=".33"/>
      <GradientStop Color="black" Offset=".33"/>
      <GradientStop Color="black" Offset=".34"/>
      <GradientStop Color="green" Offset=".34"/>
      <GradientStop Color="green" Offset=".66"/>
      <GradientStop Color="black" Offset=".66"/>
      <GradientStop Color="black" Offset=".67"/>
      <GradientStop Color="cyan" Offset=".67"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Re: your comment -- is the concern simply that it's an N amount of rectangles? If it's not a constraint that it all be one rectangle, you could do something like this:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ColorsTiles}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="100" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

and

```
ColorsTiles = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush>>() {
        new ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush>(){ new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) },
        new ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush>(){ new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSeaGreen), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) } };
```

Comment: This is a good idea to achive this, could rectangles space between them be zero?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by updating the DataTemplate, or if necessary, the ItemsPanelTemplate.