# C# WPF display several progress bars in one cell

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I need to display in a ListView a progress bar with several levels of advancement.

Concretely, I have a contract and I need to know the advancement for several operations, for example preparation is ready at 75%, assembly at 50% and welding at 25%, I would like to display something like that :

[image]

For now I found that piece of code to display one progress bar :

```
<GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Progress">
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="50" Background="WhiteSmoke" BorderThickness="1" Height="20" Opacity="0.5" Foreground="Red"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But I cannot find the way to make a "multi-levels" bar.

**Edit** : Found solution on that post : It is a way to "Shit" with Gradients
[Fill xaml rectangle multiples solidcolorbrush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947816/fill-xaml-rectangle-multiples-solidcolorbrush)

In resume, it is needed to use "LinearGradientBrush", but without gradient, my solution in XAML looks like that :

```
<GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Progress">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Name="PART_Track"  Height="20" Stroke="black" StrokeThickness="3">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0.9 0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.4"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.6"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.6"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.8"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.8"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.9"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: You need something like a StackPanel with ProgressBar for each process you've mentioned.

Comment: Сергей спасибо, I will look at StackPanel(I don't know that), Ash just wrote my post is a duplicate so I am still looking at the other post he indicated to see if I can adapt it to my code, but for now I only see LinearGradientBrush, but it doesn't help a lot...is there a way to use something similar to LinearGradientBrush, but without any Gradient?